# List all value in a column which is having 5 consecutive number, it can have any other characters as well before or after the sequence

Tags: sql-server-2008

i need only those results which is having at least one set of 5 consecutive digits in it.
This was my original query

```
  SELECT [Field]    
  FROM [testPackage].[dbo].[Table_1]
  where Field like '%[0-9]{5}%'
```

Below is the table

```
Field
---------------------
fhjsfh4324kjkjk
45654rewrwejug
g,nerht54535fjklrejltkj
fhdjfhjh425435
hjlwrjtljr424556fslfj
kljrkj67587598347rerjwlej
esd980rewrkw456
```

the query should list only

```
45654rewrwejug485345
g,nerht54535fjklrejltkj
```

Comment: Your example does not match the description

Comment: Hi please read this part
An if a string is having 5 consecutive digits as well as 6 consecutive digits that then that can be listed in this result.

And please rephrase the same if you got what i'm asking

Comment: What about 7 consecutive digits?  Would that disqualify a record, or would that also be acceptable?

Comment: that will be disqualified, at least one pattern in a string which is having 5 consecutive digits. exactly five.

Answer (score -1):

Just continue in the direction you were already heading, and repeat `[0-9]` five times in sequence inside the `LIKE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM [testPackage].[dbo].[Table_1]
WHERE Field LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z,]' OR
      Field LIKE '[a-zA-Z,][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z,]' OR
      Field LIKE '[a-zA-Z,][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' AND
      Field NOT LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Because it will give me the result which is having more than 5 consecutive digits as well

Comment: @SanuAntony You listed this in your expected result set: `45654rewrwejug485345` ... the latter part contains a six digit number.  Please explain what you want here.

Comment: But that is having at least once case which is correct, see the first part

Comment: I updated my answer.  The query is a bit ugly, but I believe it to be logically want you want.

Comment: This wont work.....
even with my sample data
My orginal query was like this 
SELECT [Field]    
  FROM [testPackage].[dbo].[Table_1]
  where Field like '%[0-9]{5}%'